# how to select a particular class onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select a particular class when it is used on multiple places .
I want to show "hide class" on clicking "feel class" , hide class and feel class is used 3 times in the document

I want to show particular "hide class" on  clicking "feel" class for the same

I tried with  `$(this).find(className) and $(clasName , this)` but it is not working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide").hide();
  $(".feel").click(function() {
    alert("s");
    $(this).find(".hide").show();
  });
});
```

```html
  
<body>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <p class="feel">
      <b> Note: </b>
   </p>
   <p class="hide"> 
      The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.
   </p>
   <p class="feel">
      <b> Note: </b>
   </p>
   <p class="hide">
      The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.
   </p>
   <p class="feel">
      <b> Note: </b>
   </p>
   <p class="hide">
      The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.
   </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting an element next to the current element so you should use jQuery's [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

`find()` is used for finding a child element within the current element, but since the element with the `hide` class is not a child of the element with the `feel` class, `find()` will not work.

But jQuery got you covered, they have `next()` which is exactly what you wanted to use in this case. What `next()` basically does is to get the element next to your current element. Since the `hide` class is just next to the `feel` class, then `next()` will work.

And you will also probably guess, the opposite of `next()` is the `prev()` which gets the element before the current element.

```js
$(".feel").click(function() {
  alert("s");
  $(this).next(".hide").show();

});
```

Here's a JS Fiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/569142/

Comment: I have used next but I am but it is not affectable

$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".disp-comment").hide();

     $(".comnt-area-view").click(function(){
  alert("hello");
  $(this).next(".disp-comment").show(1000); 
     $(".comnt-area-view").click(function(){
     $(this).next(".disp-comment").hide();


  });  });
});

Comment: Can you also post your html?  Can you also update your question  and add that code into it?

Comment: <script>


$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".disp-comment").hide();

     $(".comnt-area-view").click(function(){
  alert("hello");
  $(this).next(".disp-comment").show()
 
  });
});</script>

Answer (score 0):

You should use `next()` not `find`; check out the snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide").hide();
  $(".feel").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".hide").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="feel"><b>Note:</b></p>
<p class="hide"> The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.</p>
<p class="feel"><b>Note:</b> </p>
<p class="hide"> The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.</p>
<p class="feel"><b>Note:</b> </p>
<p class="hide"> The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.</p>
```

Comment: I have used next but I am but it is not affectable

$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".disp-comment").hide();

     $(".comnt-area-view").click(function(){
  alert("hello");
  $(this).next(".disp-comment").show(1000); 
     $(".comnt-area-view").click(function(){
     $(this).next(".disp-comment").hide();


  });  });
});

Comment: @AnuragRanjan, check the snippet

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery `next()` in this case.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide").hide();
  $(".feel").click(function() {
    alert("s");
    $(this).next().show();
  });
});
```

```html
  
<body>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <p class="feel">
      <b> Note: </b>
   </p>
   <p class="hide"> 
      The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.
   </p>
   <p class="feel">
      <b> Note: </b>
   </p>
   <p class="hide">
      The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.
   </p>
   <p class="feel">
      <b> Note: </b>
   </p>
   <p class="hide">
      The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.
   </p>
</body>
```

However lets say you want to find out what the very next element with a specific class then you could use `next('selector-here')`

Eg:

```
  $(".feel").click(function() {
    alert("s");
    $(this).next(".hide").show();
  });
```

Comment: I have used next but I am but it is not affectable

$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".disp-comment").hide();

     $(".comnt-area-view").click(function(){
  alert("hello");
  $(this).next(".disp-comment").show(1000); 
     $(".comnt-area-view").click(function(){
     $(this).next(".disp-comment").hide();


  });  });
});